# Missing Back and Share Button Using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

I'm relatively new to Objective-C.

I'm working my way through creating an app just now and, as far as I'm aware, using the 'push' segue should create a back button in the navigation bar?

This worked for my initial view controller which goes from a table view to a `UIView`. The new one goes from a table view to just a basic view.

Below is the section of my storyboard I'm referencing.

Does anyone know why these buttons are missing (I've added code for the share button as well which works on the `UIView` as well)?

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cihX.png

Comment: What happens when you grab the left side of the screen and drag right?  Maybe post a screen shot of the screen where you expect a back button.

Comment: @NealEhardt 
Expected results: http://imgur.com/EvKRXhT,lTL9ZI4#1

Actual results: http://imgur.com/EvKRXhT,lTL9ZI4#0

Comment: That's very odd.  Do you see the segue animation when it's pushed onto the navigation controller?  And as I asked before, can you do the swipe-back gesture?

Comment: @NealEhardt Yeah, I see the animation and can swipe. Everything seems the same to the first one, extremely confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

It was due to the layout of my navigation controllers in my main storyboard. I had an extra one that was causing issues.